# Regular Expression to find \"

Tags: php, regex

What's the regular expression to find `\"`

I think it's this: `'/\\"/'` but I need to use it on a really large dataset so need to make sure this is correct.

I need to replace it with `"` so my code is : `$data = preg_replace('/\\"/', '"', $data)`

Is that correct?

Comment: You need 4 backslashes. PHP will eat up half because of required string value escaping. Thus 2 backslashes will arrive in the PCRE C function, which are required because the backslash in a regex needs to be escaped with itself. (Otherwise it would -needlessly- apply to the double quote).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For matching backslashes you need to 'double-escape' them, so you have four `\` at the end:

```
$data = preg_replace('/\\\\"/', '"', $data);
```

Why you need 4 `\`: PHP parses a string `\\"` as `\"` and RegEx interprets this as `"` since in RegEx you don't need to escape `"`. So it wont match `\"`. `\\\\"` will be parsed as `\\"` which will be interpreted as `\"` by RegEx.

Comment: Yep. My bad. You've got it right. (Not my downvote, though, so I can't remove it. Sorry.)

Comment: So is this one correct one or the one I have above? I don't understand the 4 backslashes. Not my downvote either.

Comment: Am I needing to escape the double quote also? Is that the reason for four?

Comment: @JMC: When the single-quoted string is interpolated, the 4 slashes go to 2. When the string in the forward slashes is interpolated, the two go to 1.

Comment: @Floern: But why does preg_quote returns only two? http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/87df7.php

Comment: @genesis: `preg_quote('\\"')` is the same as `\\\\"` (both will be echo'd as `\\"`) - and `preg_quote('\"')` is actually the same as `preg_quote('"')`

Answer (score 5):

A backslash does not need to be escaped in either a single-quoted string or a regular expression, unless the following character is a character that can be escaped (such as the backslash itself).

A double quote does not need to be escaped and cannot be escaped in a single-quoted string. In a regular expression it doesn't have to be either, but it *can* be.

That means `\\` in both a single-quoted string and a regular expression becomes `\`, while `\"` in a single-quoted string remains `\"`, while in a regular expression it becomes `"`.

However, in PHP you can only create a regular expression from a string, so you have to escape twice.

In other words...

```
Original string    String processed   Regexp processed
'/\"/'             /\"/               "
'/\\"/'            /\"/               "
'/\\\"/'           /\\"/              \"
'/\\\\"/'          /\\"/              \"
'/\\\\\"/'         /\\\"/             \"
'/\\\\\\"/'        /\\\"/             \"
'/\\\\\\\"/'       /\\\\"/            \\"
```

#### Bonus backslash

In a double-quoted string, of course, the `"` does need to be escaped, so...

```
"/\"/"             /"/                "
"/\\"/"            syntax error
"/\\\"/"           /\"/               "
"/\\\\"/"          syntax error
"/\\\\\"/"         /\\"/              \"
"/\\\\\\"/"        syntax error
"/\\\\\\\"/"       /\\\"/             \"
"/\\\\\\\\"/"      syntax error
"/\\\\\\\\\"/"     /\\\\"/            \\"
```

I think you should probably go for `preg_replace("/\\\\\\\"/", "\"", $data)` just to be on the <s>safe</s>confusing side.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you mean the literal string `\"`, matching for those characters in a regular expression requires:

```
 \\"
```

So, you'd use `/\\\\"/` as the pattern parameter in a preg_* function.
(You only need to escape the backslash - since [PHP handles backslashes in single and double-quotes strings as a special character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), you need to escape them twice.)

Is this *all* you need to match? If so, I'd recommend just using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$string = str_replace('\\"', '"', $string);
```

For a simple search/replace of literal characters like this, an iterative string function like `str_replace()` will be faster than a regular expression.

Comment: @JMC I can't see anything in your question that requires `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`. @Chris the `'/"'` in your `str_replace` answer should be `'\"'` (or `'\\"'`).

Answer (score 2):

this one is correct.

```
preg_replace('/\\\"/', '"', $data);
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/1283c.php

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, backslashes have special meaning. You can therefore represent a literal backslash as either of the following: `\\\` or `\\\\`. The alternative method is to use a character class: `[\\]`.

Refer to the section labeled "Note" here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: this doesn't match `\"` since PHP parser reads the string `'\\"'` as `\"` and RegEx interprets it as an escaped quote which is equal to `"`, not `\"`

Comment: @JaredNg: Looks weird, but this answer is wrong: http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/87df7.php

Comment: @genesis Actually still in the middle of editing, I have the edit box open in a different tab. I'm aware that this is actually not correct (yet).

Comment: Okay, edits finished. As I mentioned, I upvoted Floern's answer for coming up with the correct answer first.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work just as well for your data?

```
str_replace('\\"','"',$data);
```

Comment: He's needing to match the backslash followed by a double-quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\\\\"/i', '"', $subject);
```